# How to build a jar without "-SNAPSHOT" in the name with Gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build

Every time I run this command: `gradle build` it produces a `my-program-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Where do I control this? In the `gradle.properties` I have only the version nothing else. Even if I run `gradle -Dversion=1.0.0 build` it still creates a jar with SNAPSHOT in the name. How do I create a jar like this: `my-program-1.0.0.jar`?

I'm using spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically we have to change the project version in the gradle, To do so we have to use project api in gradle. you can refer https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html

One Solution I can suggest is:

1. Add `version '1.0'` in your build.gradle

Comment: As you suggested it does work. But I'd like to change the version from my build pipeline. So incrementing this value in the build.gradle file isn't really ideal. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution how to run it from the build pipeline @LagSurfer?